# Populating data on Gridview using Thread

Tags: multithreading, datagridview, using

I have a winform Datagridview control in my form on load i populate nearly 1000 and more records. Every few seconds data is fetched from my sql server and has to be populated on the grid. I dont want my grid to freeze. Please help me with this.....

Answer (score 0):

1. Put the population code into a method.
2. Put a loop in the method so that runs until a boolean variable is set to TRUE.
3. Create a thread object that calls that method.
4. Start the thread object.
5. When the method needs to update the grid, you MUST use a DELEGATE and the DataGridView.Invoke method to update the grid; otherwise you will get threading errors.
6. When you want to cancel the thread, set the variable to TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a Timer and when it ticks create a new thread and update the `DataGrid`.

*Example with Windows Forms and TPL (.NET Framework 4 and 3.5).*

Initialize the timer:

```
this.timer = new Timer() { Interval = 2000 };
this.timer.Tick += OnFetch;
this.timer.Start();
```

Manage the Tick Event:

```
private void OnFetch(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        // Get the data from your db
        var data = GetDbData();
        foreach (MyElement row in data)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                dataGridView1.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    // Add the row
                }));
            }
        }
    });
}
```